# spring security - one active role

Tags: security, grails, spring-security

Imagine that users can have one or more roles in the system. after 
login the user have to choose on of these roles. at this point only 
this selected role should be checked by spring security.

e.g. user has ROLE_A, ROLE_B

requestmaps:

/book/** -> ROLE_A, ROLE_B 
/author/** -> ROLE A

the normal behaviour would be that user can access all defined 
actions. in my special case the user would select ROLE_A and then get 
access only for /author/** actions. in other words, it is possible to 
define one active role in the security context, so that spring 
security would perform security checks based on this single role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I would suggest avoiding this approach, from an end user perspective, I understand sometimes there are requirements out of your control.  So with that said, note that the Person object you've defined for Spring Security to use should contain the following:

```
Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
   PersonRole.findAllByPerson(this).collect { it.role } as Set
}
```

If you define a property somewhere that specified your selected Role, just modify the above method to only return that role.

Comment: thanks for this solution! my approach was to modify the authorities collection in the user detial class after login, so that only one role exists in this collection. the user can also swith the role. at this moment you have to modify this collection again.